# How to fix property file is undefined in ion-input type file

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I'm developing Ionic 3 mobile app and I want to upload images from the mobile app to web API. For that, I'm using POST method to send the image. I'm trying to upload the image as a multipart file because the server is expecting a multipart file. Therefore I added an input field to choose the file such as. Next, I created the `changeListener()` event to send the image to the server.

```
<ion-input type="file" accept="image/*" id="upload" [(ngModel)]="imagePath" (ionChange)="changeListener($event)"></ion-input>


changeListener($event): void {
     this.imagePath = $event.target.files[0];
     console.log($event.target.files[0])
     this.imageProvider.uploadImage(this.imagePath)
}
```

When I choose the file it's giving me a typeError such as "cannot read the property file of undefined".
Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: Can you add to your post the content of the `$event`?

Comment: I added the HTML part

Comment: What does `console.log($event)` print?

Comment: TextInput {_config: Config, _elementRef: ElementRef, _renderer: RendererAdapter, _componentName: "input", _mode: "md", …}autocomplet …}_readonly: false_relocated: false_renderer: RendererAdapter {delegate: DebugRenderer2}_scrollData: null_type: "file"_useAssist: true_value: "C:\fakepath\15915100635_fdd8bc8554_k.jpg"__proto__: BaseInput

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `ionChange` to `change`.

```
<ion-input type="file" accept="image/*" id="upload" 
        [(ngModel)]="imagePath" 
        (change)="changeListener($event)"></ion-input>
```

[Working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-c3zhqd?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html)

Comment: I change the code now I'm getting another error such as "Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string"

Comment: Then accept this as correct answer and post your new error as a new question.